# opencv-webcam stream cannot be received by another process via named fifo

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, systems-programming

Hi i am trying to simulate a client-server program.Both are independent processes.The client listens for image data(mat.data) written on a **named fifo** by the server (which reads image frames from a webcam and writes them one by one on the namedfifo)
My server and client sides work perfectly, if I create a simple mat object on the client side ,write it on the fifo,read it on the server and recreate it on the server side.However, when I try to write a continuous stream of frames
from webcam, the server gives core-dump, segmentation fault.

The **server** side code is shown below.

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
     #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
     #include <iostream>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <sys/types.h>
     #include <sys/stat.h>
     #include <fcntl.h>
     #include <unistd.h>
     int main(int, char**)
     {
      VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
      if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
       return -1;

      int check;
      int fd;
      int totalbytes;
      int buflen;

      fd = open("/home/vidfifo",O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK);

      for(;;)
      {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera

        int  totalbytes = frame.total()*frame.elemSize();
        int buflen = frame.cols*3;

        check = writefifo(frame.data,totalbytes,buflen,fd);

        if (check == 1)
        {
          cout<<"write successful"<<endl;
          imshow("frames1", frame);
          if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
        }
        else
        {
          break;
        }
    }
       close(fd);
       return 0;
    }
```

the **writefifo** function is as follows

```
    int writefifo(uchar *framepointer,int totalbytes,int buflen,int fd)
    {
      uchar* buf;
      buf = framepointer;
      int num = totalbytes/buflen;
      for(int i = 1;i<=num;i++)
      {
        write(fd,buf,buflen);
        buf = buf + buflen;
      }
      return 1;
     }
```

the **client** side is

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    int main( int argc, char** argv )
    {
      //I found these by running the server program beforehand          
      int rows = 480;
      int cols = 640;
      int nchan = 3;
      int totalbytes = 921600;//rows*cols*nchan
      int buflen = 1920;//cols*nchan

      while(1)
      {
         Mat img(rows,cols,CV_8UC3);
         uchar buf[buflen];
         uchar datarray[totalbytes];

         int fd1 = open("/home/vidfifo",O_RDONLY);
         int j;
         int k = 0;
         int num = totalbytes/buflen;//=num of rows

         for(int i = 1;i<=num;i++)
         {
           read(fd1,buf,buflen);
           for ( j = 0 ; j<= (buflen-1);j++ ) //originally wrote this as j<= (buflen-1+k)--see update1 at the end of post
           {
              datarray[j+k] = buf[j];

           }
              k = k+buflen;
           }

           img.data = datarray;
           imshow("framesrec", img);
           if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
     }
            return 0;
     }
```

I know there's something wrong with a pointer in the server program.But I can't figure out what.
Please tell me if there is some pointer related issue or something else in the code that does not allow the client to receive a continuous stream of frames.
Thanks.

**update1** after posting this question, I realized I should have written the limit of the read loop( in server) as *j<=(buflen -1)* instead of *j<=(buflen-1+k)*.This removed the segmentation error, but all I get is a corrupted frozen frame instead of a continuous stream  and the window stops responding after some time.So, now my question is How do I get a continuous stream?

**update2** after putting the close system call outside loop in the server code, i now get a continuous stream but it is blurred and frames appear squashed.Still not a perfect stream.

Comment: Make sure you open the device before the loop and close after. At least the first example has such error of closing the file in the loop. And make it properly indented / formatted. The rest I am not sure of.

Comment: yea that helps with the stream but it is blurry